# Console Color Background Color Not Changing

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, windows-console

I have a static method that I want to use to change the Console.BackgroundColor if it's running under the test environment. When I break on the line after the color is changed is is still set to Black.

```
public static void LogError(string err)
{
    if (IsRunningFromMspec)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
        Console.WriteLine(" &&&" + err);
    }
    else if (MyTracer.MyLevelSwitch.TraceError && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(err))
    {
       Trace.TraceError(" &&& - " + err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Console.BackgroundColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.console.backgroundcolor) does not change the background color of the whole console window. It only changes the background color of the text you will write *after* you set that color.

So your output `Console.WriteLine(" &&&" + err);` will now be written with a `DarkRed` background:

[image]

As Ian H. pointed out in the comments, to set the whole console window's background to the desired color call

```
Console.Clear();
```

after you changed the color. But of course this will delete all the content you previously wrote, which you perhaps don't want.

Comment: To paint the entire background, execute `Console.Clear();` after setting the background color.

Comment: @IanH. ah right, nice, forgot about that (I think I remember I knew it once). Thx, I'll add it for completeness.

Comment: The Windows APIs to call are [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683171) to get the current `srWindow`, for the start coordinate and number of character cells to read via [`ReadConsoleOutputAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684968). Modify the background color for each cell and write the attribute data back via [`WriteConsoleOutputAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687407).